# Scala convert type parameter to Double

Tags: scala

I have this class defined:

```
class LinearEquations[T <% Double](var y: MLVector[T],var rows: MLMatrix[T]) {
def largestPivot(p: Int): Int = {
    var pivot = rows(p)(p).abs //Error here: value abs is not a member of type parameter T
    //more code
}
```

where

```
type MLMatrix[T] = Array[Array[T]]
```

Now, in another class I'm creating the object LinearEquations (assume MLMatrix is filled with Doubles):

```
var rows = new MLMatrix[Double](4)//now fill with Doubles
val le = new LinearEquations(y, rows)
```

There's some type of implicit conversion I have to do but I'm not sure how to do it. The constructor receives a Type Parameter but when I instanciate the class I pass a Double.

thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] of your problem. What is `y` and `rows`, and where are they created? Also, view bounds are deprecated.

Comment: Quite a few statements and no question. What about asking a question? Do you get an error? What is the problem?

Comment: How about read what I wrote.Don't you see an error?value abs is not a member of type parameter T

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Perhaps it's because you put it like a comment in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
10.0.abs
```

works thanks to implicit conversion to type `RichDouble` defined within `Predef`:

```
@inline implicit def doubleWrapper(x: Double)   = new runtime.RichDouble(x)
```

However compiler cannot just treat `T` like `Double` in some cases because of reasons.

There are solutions to this problem though, e.g. type classes:

```
trait MathsOps[T] {

  def abs(num: T): T
}

implicit object DoubleOps extends MathOps[Double] {
   def abs(num: Double) = num.abs
}

class LinearEquations[T : MathsOps](var y: MLVector[T], var rows: MLMatrix[T]) {
def largestPivot(p: Int): Int = {
    var pivot = implicitly[MathOps[T]].abs(rows(p)(p))
    //more code
}
```

This could be easily extended by providing new implicits for all possible `T` you'd use.

To restore the syntax you could define another implicit class:

```
implicit class RichMathSyntax[T : MathOps](value: T) {

  def abs = implicitly[MathOps[T]].abs(value)
}
```

This should work for any numeric type that you might want to pass into `LinearEquations`.

Comment: And this is what I was looking for. Awesome answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  class LinearEquations[T <% Double](var y: Array[Array[T]], var rows: Array[Array[T]]) {
    def largestPivot(p: Int): Int = {
      var pivot = rows(p)(p) //Error here: value abs is not a member of type parameter T
      val res: Double = scala.math.abs(pivot)
      //more code
      0
    }
  }
```

It compiled for me

Comment: This works but I was looking for a more scala way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out Spire open source math project: 
https://github.com/non/spire

It has a lot of good code for generic math. I use it myself and have been happy with it.